# How to maintain simple database in git?

Tags: json, git, merge, version-control, git-merge-conflict

I have a JSON (multiline) file with lots of project settings and a list of included modules for a few projects. It's version-controlled by git with the same repository as my projects. It is constantly growing and works just fine to set up and tune my projects. The only problem is, when working with team and branches I constantly have merge conflicts that need to be solved manually, and 99% of cases is "use both" because it's just new entries. So what are the alternatives? I need to have the same version and branching in this database since it has project settings and dependencies, but I want to reduce conflicts to a minimum. And I do not want a separate database, that I need to maintain in parallel with git, they need to perfectly sync automatically when switching between different branches or commits. Thanks!

Comment: A single-line JSON is really tricky for most version control systems because they operate on entire lines. YAML is less prone to merge conflicts because each change goes on a separate line.

Comment: we use multi-line json, but git always conflicts even on two new lines added from different branches to same place

Comment: Well, two new lines added from different branches to the same place is the canonical example of a merge conflict. The standard diff algorithm has no way of knowing if two new key/value pairs, for example, should *be* two separate additions or if it's one addition but with a typo in one or both. At the very least, you would need a configuration file with a stricter schema than what JSON provides and a diff tool that *knows* about that schema.